# How to remove if statement with an if statement? as3

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, flash-cs5, visible

I'm making a game where the character has to pass through the gate after getting the key
so when he gets the key the gate is suppose to go away, i used

```
if(character.hitTestObject(gate))
{character.visible = false;                   
youLose_text.visible = true; }
```

**BUT when he gets the key: it's**

```
if(character.hitTestObject(key))
{
   gate.visible = false; }
```

NOW when i pass through the gate, i obviously get killed again
**now how do i remove the previous if function through the next if function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the gate is supposed to actually "go away", you should completely remove it, not just make it invisible... e.g.:

```
if(character.hitTestObject(key)) {
    //don't forget to remove event listeners on the gate as well, if it had any
    removeChild(gate);
    gate = null;
} else if(gate != null) {
    if(character.hitTestObject(gate)) {
        character.visible = false;
        youLose_text.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually answered my question perfectly i was looking for the
removeChild and gate = null thing

Answer (score 3):

Just set/check a boolean. One already exists in `gate.visible`.

```
// If gate is visible and character hitTests gate then..
if(gate.visible && character.hitTestObject(gate)) {
    character.visible = false;                   
    youLose_text.visible = true; 
}
```

Comment: It didnt work, I want it to be like: If gate is not visible and character passes through the gate place, the hitTestObject should not work

Comment: @PituObito Then change `!gate.visible` to `gate.visible`. This is just a question about the "not" operator.

Comment: hey thanks for replying but it still doesnt work xD
when the character goes through the space where the gate is suppose to be (Which is not visible after you get the key) the HitTestObject still responds, i want to deactivate it so that the character doesnt lose when he hits the non visible gate

Comment: @PituObito Then set a boolean (eg. `gotKey = true`) and use `if (!gotKey && character.hitTestObject(Gate))`.